# .net graphing library with dragable data points

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graph

I am looking for a graphing library that I can use in a C# application. I am hoping to find one that is free and would allow me to create a line graph that end-users could modify by dragging data points.

If anyone knows of one that can do this let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: 404 error on your jpg-link...

Comment: WinForms. Should have mentioned that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is possible with both MsChart and ZedGraphs.

MsChart: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/MSWinWebChart/thread/2bc4823c-1365-40ee-a239-b6f0c65a539a

ZedGraphs: http://goorman.free.fr/ZedGraph/zedgraph.org/wiki/indexa9f9.html

Answer (score 1):

[Piccolo](http://code.google.com/p/piccolo2d/) is pretty good as well.